# Unsupported HZ resolution

Tags: windows, graphics-card

I have trouble with my display adapter Intel HD Graphics driver. Out of curiosity I changed the refresh rate from 60hz to 100hz. But that turns my monitor into black and says 1024*768 60hz. I know that it is because I change the refresh rate which is unsupported.

Now my question is how to make the settings in my graphics driver back to its original state. It can't load when I'm using safe mode . Is their any way to make it back to 60hz?

Changing registry I think but whats the name and registry value

Answer (score 2):

Most drivers ask if the display is OK after you change resolutions or refresh rate. If you just wait it will revert back to the previous setting. In the future if the screen is messed up don't press any keys or click the mouse button and it will revert after a short delay.

To fix an accepted unsupported refresh rate or resolution:

(Vista, 7 and 8) While booting press F8, the Advanced Boot Options menu will come up, in the list shown scroll down past the various Safe Modes and select "Enable low-resolution video (640x480)" which has the description "Set or reset the display resolution. Start Windows in low-resolution display mode (640x480)." You will now boot in a low resolution mode and besides having to scroll around a lot to use dialogs you can change the resolution and refresh rate to something supported by your monitor.

(XP) Same F8, menu option in the Windows Advanced Options Menu is "Enable VGA Mode".

Comment: do you think sir i can run my display adapter without making my screen turns into black with message 1024*768 60hz ^_^ i have intel HD Graphics display adapter . i want to configure it again back to 60hz . that setting makes my monitor black ^_^ can i run the UI of intel to configure the settings ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is quite old question, but I run into the same problem today and solved it and I want to share my experience.

### tldr:

Chose one:

- Grab another display, connect with in the original one simultaneously
  and change refresh rate.
- In a desperate situation install a vnc server (tightvnc for example) and change refresh rate within remote session.

### Detailed answer:

Actually its a **PURE NIGHTMARE**. I spent nearly 3 hours to solve this simple (at first glance) problem. It looks like Microsoft and Intel developers took any measures to make changing refresh rate blindly impossible.

Boot mode with reduced video parameters wont help, since it changes resolution only, not the refresh rate. Safe mode wont help you either, since it use a virtual graphics adapter and configuring it - don`t affect real one at all. There is no way to change refresh rate via console or hotkey (prove me wrong here if someone can).

I tried to delete VGA driver with device manager in safe mode and install it again in normal mode - the beast remembers its options and especially previously configured frame rate! I tried to connect another display *instead* of original one and again - Windows remembers all options per display. My PC does not allow to connect 2 displays simultaneously, so that was out of option for me, but it looks like its best solution by now.

So, I tried enabling RDP service from safe mode to be able to see what happening on screen with remote session. Truns out, that its impossible to change display parameters from RDP session! But then, in an RDP session - its possible to install VNC server (its impossible to do that in the safe mode) and with help of a VNC server, finally, its possible to change the refresh rate.